# How to drag and drop directory and get only the path of it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

How can i drag and drop directory in windows and get the path of the directory - that is in order to not to write the path by myself all the time (*sometimes its really long*).

I tried to look for a solution but couldn't find as most drag and drop that relate to directory or files just getting the directory file list.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping directories is supported in input type "file" on Chome, however I don't think you will be able to get the full path easily, due to security reasons.
Take a loot at the example:

```
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {
  var length = e.dataTransfer.items.length;
    var entry = e.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (entry.isDirectory) {
        alert(entry.fullPath);
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zp574g63/1/